# Using large amounts of if-else statements for playing card numbers

Tags: java, strings, playing-cards

I have a method that uses a bunch of `if-else` statements, and I am thinking how I could simplify it.

```
public static CardNumber decode(String s) {
    if(s == null) {
        return null;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(ACE.toString())) {
        return ACE;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(TWO.toString())) {
        return TWO;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(THREE.toString())) {
        return THREE;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(FOUR.toString())) {
        return FOUR;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(FIVE.toString())) {
        return FIVE;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(SIX.toString())) {
        return SIX;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(SEVEN.toString())) {
        return SEVEN;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(EIGHT.toString())) {
        return EIGHT;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(NINE.toString())) {
        return NINE;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(TEN.toString())) {
        return TEN;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(JACK.toString())) {
        return JACK;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(QUEEN.toString())) {
        return QUEEN;
    } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(KING.toString())) {
        return KING;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The whole class is here:

```
public class CardNumber {
    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    public static final CardNumber ACE_AS_ONE = new CardNumber("A", 1);
    public static final CardNumber TWO = new CardNumber("2", 2);
    public static final CardNumber THREE = new CardNumber("3", 3);
    public static final CardNumber FOUR = new CardNumber("4", 4);
    public static final CardNumber FIVE = new CardNumber("5", 5);
    public static final CardNumber SIX = new CardNumber("6", 6);
    public static final CardNumber SEVEN = new CardNumber("7", 7);
    public static final CardNumber EIGHT = new CardNumber("8", 8);
    public static final CardNumber NINE = new CardNumber("9", 9);
    public static final CardNumber TEN = new CardNumber("10", 10);
    public static final CardNumber JACK = new CardNumber("J", 11);
    public static final CardNumber QUEEN = new CardNumber("Q", 12);
    public static final CardNumber KING = new CardNumber("K", 13);
    public static final CardNumber ACE = new CardNumber("A", 14);

    private CardNumber(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static CardNumber decode(String s) {
        if(s == null) {
            return null;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(ACE.toString())) {
            return ACE;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(TWO.toString())) {
            return TWO;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(THREE.toString())) {
            return THREE;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(FOUR.toString())) {
            return FOUR;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(FIVE.toString())) {
            return FIVE;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(SIX.toString())) {
            return SIX;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(SEVEN.toString())) {
            return SEVEN;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(EIGHT.toString())) {
            return EIGHT;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(NINE.toString())) {
            return NINE;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(TEN.toString())) {
            return TEN;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(JACK.toString())) {
            return JACK;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(QUEEN.toString())) {
            return QUEEN;
        } else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(KING.toString())) {
            return KING;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still want to have all the power of a class instead of an enum, another solution would be to use a map:

```
public class CardNumber {
    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    private static final Map<String, CardNumber> cards = new HashMap<>(14);

    static {
        cards.put("A", new CardNumber("A", 1));
        //[...]
        cards.put("K", new CardNumber("K", 13));
    }

    // [... constructor ...]

    public static CardNumber decode(String s) {
        if(s == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return cards.get(s);
        }
    }

    // [... toString, getValue ...]
}
```

Comment: With a private constructor there's no need for a class. What's this 'power of a class' that you speak of?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I overlooked the private keyword. And I'm talking about extending, etc.

Comment: OK, extending I can agree with. Although you don't get much use of extending if the superclass has a private constructor. What's the 'etc.' part? :)

Comment: Well, you can't create new instances of them. So for example if we have two sets of cards (which is not that uncommon), and the cards have a state (for example open on the table or not), that would not be possible with an enum. Although I get your point, that would require a restructure of the class anyways.

Comment: Additionally, with an enum, you'd get a hashCode + equals implementation for free! Not that you need one right now because essentially, this class has been written as if it was an enum already...

Comment: @tim By two sets of cards, do you mean suits? And card states in a game? Those should be handled by a `Suit` and `Game` type respectively... :)

Comment: @h.j.k. I was thinking of games like blackjack, where you have two or more sets of card-decks.

Comment: @tim I see, sorry for the misinterpretation. ;)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Sure, you get a `hashCode`, but a non-deterministic one! This is OK unless you run into some rare bug in your code which can't be reproduced because of this.

Comment: @maaartinus I have to admit I did believe enum.hashCode was implemented in another way, [apparently I was wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4885292/1310566). I do however still believe that the way this class is defined, it would still be better as an enum **(you could still use the map though)**

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I'd go for an `enum`, too, but it's much better if its `hashCode` wasn't `final`. Another reason against final is the usage in ETag (HTTP Response Header) as mentioned in a comment to the linked question of mine.

Answer (score 13):

Convert your constant values to an `enum` instead, for example:

```
enum Card {
    ACE_AS_ONE("A", 1),
    TWO("2", 2),
    THREE("3", 3),
    // and so on
    KING("K", 10);

    private final String name;
    private final int value;

    Card(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Card decode(String name) {
        for (Card card : Card.values()) {
            if (card.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return card;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

While at it, add some unit tests to verify, for example:

```
public class CardTest {
    @Test
    public void testDecodeNumeric() {
        assertEquals(Card.TWO, Card.decode("2"));
        assertEquals(Card.THREE, Card.decode("3"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDecodeLabeled() {
        assertEquals(Card.KING, Card.decode("K"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNonexistent() {
        assertNull(Card.decode("nonexistent"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDecodeNull() {
        assertNull(Card.decode(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `ACE_AS_ONE`, given that in some card games 'Ace' can optionally represent the biggest value in a suit as well.

Comment: Thanks @h.j.k. but `ACE_AS_ONE` was the OP's idea, not mine ;-)

Comment: After a more detailed review, that means OP's code is buggy too... `"A"` will always give you `CardNumber("A", 14)`. Oh wells...

Comment: Yes, he can't get `Card.ACE_AS_ONE` through `.decode`, but we don't know the rest of his code and it might be acceptable for him, who knows.

Comment: I'd drop `value` in favor of `ordinal()+1`. This may stop working if the requirements change, but they won't (and simpler code now is better than some theoretical flexibility).